# How to connect a Java Project to a MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've been browsing the internet for an up-to-date way to connect a Java project to a MySQL server/document. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Everything I've found just seems to use links to out-of-date software.**

Comment: Take a look above duplicate question this should help you.

Comment: You might find this [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to a specific database type, such in your case, it is the best way to look first for a official library.

In the case of MySQL you can find this connector here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking online for MySQL JDBC but I guess they changed it to just J. Super helpful!

Comment: @Yordle_ The JDBC driver for MySQL has always been called MySQL Connector/J as far as I am aware. However the first hit when I search for _MySQL JDBC_ is the MySQL Connector/J download page.